# I want to output "<PID> Killed ~" to logfile when it kill -9 <PID>

Tags: linux, bash, kill

I want to output this message `/usr/local/ex1.sh: line xxx: <PID> Killed ex2.sh >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1` to logfile.

however

The "ex1.sh" output `/usr/local/ex1.sh: line xxx: <PID> Killed ex2.sh >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1` to console when I executed `ex1.sh` in console.

The result that i want is that "ex1.sh" output to file, not that output to console.

This source is "ex1.sh".

```
ex2.sh >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1 &
PID=`ps -ef | grep ex2.sh | grep -v grep | gawk '{print $2}'`
/bin/kill -9 $PID >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1 &
```

Why does "ex1.sh" output this message to console?

Comment: Why are you running `kill` in the background?

Comment: Because I want to check stop the process as asynchronous processing.

I tried to execute in sync.
But i can not output to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is in fact not written by the `kill` command or `ex2.sh`. It is written by the shell executing the background process `ex2.sh`.

The shell executing the script started the script `ex2.sh` in the background as a child process and is monitoring it. When the script is killed, the shell acts on this by printing the message.

In your special case the shell knows more about the killed process and the process executing kill. So it prints a rather verbose message.

If you start `ex2.sh` (without '&') in terminal 1  and kill it from terminal 2, the shell in terminal 1 will just print "Killed".

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that message `'/usr/local/ex1.sh: line xxx: <PID> Killed ex2.sh >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1` is given by **bash shell**, not by `kill` command.

So if you redirect `kill` command output to a file, you will not get the message in the file.

If running like `./ex1.sh >> $LOG_FILE 2&>1`, the message will be in the log file. Because `./ex1.sh` forks a new bash process, the bash process will give out the message.